# multi-language translations

Tags: language

I need to add text to the payment methods box in the checkout process.

I've narrowed the file down to payment.html, and worked out where the message code should go.

However, this code needs to be multi-language, changing from English to German, as I switch store language etc.

How can I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the line where you add your static

```
<option value="someValue">The Message you want translated</option>
```

message,

```
<option value="someValue"><?php Mage::helper('checkout')->__('The Message you want translated')></option>
```

Go to

```
app/locale/de_DE
```

find the Mage_Checkout.csv, open it and add to the bottom

> "The Message you want translated","Your German Translation goes here"

that should it.

Please note, if you install future updates of the German Language Pack, you will loose your translation.

Comment: Thanks - I'm actually inserting the message manually at present. So I need to make that link myself I guess? Any tips on how to do that?

Comment: Ah, no. I thought you found the respective line and have edited it. If not this answer is not precisely of use to you.


Where and how exactly are you inserting your message ?
Are you adding to a static  <option> tag ?

Comment: just as a simple html insert, hard coded into the page. After some more browsing, I'm thinking I need to do something like this?> http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/12256/translate-csv-failed-to-overwrite-module-translation?rq=1

Comment: enter like this: <?php echo $this->__(“my message”); ?> and then put into the csv?

Comment: updated the answer.